# Constrain enum type in method parameter to user defined enum(s)

Tags: c#, sqlite, methods, enums

I have a small, fixed number of enums in their own `.cs` file in my custom namespace. Most of the enum names is the prefix of the corresponding table name in my SQLite database. As such, the string and int values in each enum are the record values for name and id respectively, therefore allowing me to easily keep track of which data to pass in methods that perform an SQL query.

```
public enum TableNamePrefix //respective table name would be "TableNamePrefix_SomeNameHere"
    {
        value1 = 1, //name = "value1", id = 1
        value2 = 2, //name = "value2", id = 2
        //...
    }

public enum TableNamePrefix2
    {
        //...
    }

//...
```

The goal is to simplify my database search criteria whenever I do a query which would heavily limit the chance of receiving a null record. Here is one of the methods I use to return a table row.

```
public static T GetTableRow(DBTableNameAbberviations tableNameAbb, Enum prefix,
            string keyword = "", string name = "") //tableNameAbb is another enum
```

The method above works as expected, but I don't want `Enum prefix` to allow any `Enum` to be passed in, which brings me to my question. Is there a way to constrain this to a single or multiple user defined enums? In other words, rather than pass in any generic enum to my second parameter, is there a way to limit it to `TableNamePrefix` and my other omitted enums? If not, then what could a workaround be?

I thought about using a generic method with constraints, but `where T2: System.Enum` would still allow any `Enum` to be used.

Comment: Instead of enums you could create strongly typed classes with public static properties like `public class TableNamePrefix { public int Value {get;set;} private TableNamePrefix(int value) => Value = value; public static TableNamePrefix Value1 {get;} = new TableNamePrefix(1); public static TableNamePrefix Value2 {get;} = new TablenamePrefix(2);}` then you could apply an interface to the classes you want to allow and use that.

Comment: [Type Safe Enum](https://www.meziantou.net/smart-enums-type-safe-enums-in-dotnet.htm), I think this is in line with @juharr's comment.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this helps your searching? Probably because it's a Friday, but I don't understand what this accomplishes. Perhaps a couple of actual sample `Enums`, like one for `Customer` and one for `Order` or something. I don't get what the `id` refers to.

Comment: Constrain to enum and `IWhatever`. All your enums will implement `IWhatever`.

Comment: @RufusL I didn't include an example of how I use that method to perform a query because it's not relevant to my question about constraining user-defined enum types. But the idea is to always pass in known table record ids via use of enums so I or others will always know what record id will be accepted by the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using a type safe enum, since it seems you have additional data you want to accompany your enum.

This is the base class we will use for our type safe enums. It provides the basics for all type safe enums, the value and the name.

```
 public abstract class TypeSafeEnumBase<TValue>
    {
        public readonly TValue Value;
        public readonly string Name;

        protected TypeSafeEnumBase(TValue value, string name)
        {
            this.Value = value;
            this.Name = name;            
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }

        private static TypeSafeEnumBase<TValue>[] Items { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<TypeSafeEnumBase<TValue>> GetValues<TType>()
        {
            if (Items == null || Items.Length == 0)
            {
                Dictionary<string, TType> items = typeof(TType)
                    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                    .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(TType))
                    .ToDictionary(f => f.Name,
                        f => (TType)f.GetValue(null));
                Items = items.Values.Cast<TypeSafeEnumBase<TValue>>().ToArray();
            }

            foreach (TypeSafeEnumBase<TValue> item in Items)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is your 'table details' setup as a type safe enum. In this class we implement any additional properties that may be needed, e.g. Prefix, Keyword, etc.

```
public sealed class TableDetails : TypeSafeEnumBase<int>
    {
        public static TableDetails TableOneDetails = new TableDetails(1, "value1", "TableNamePrefix1","table1keyword");
        public static TableDetails TableTwoDetails = new TableDetails(2, "value2","TableNamePrefix2", "table2keyword");
        public static TableDetails TableThreeDetails = new TableDetails(3, "value3", "TableNamePrefix3", "table3keyword");

        public TableDetails(int value, string name, string prefix, string keyword) : base(value, name)
        {
            Prefix = prefix;
            Keyword = keyword;
        }

        public string Prefix { get; }
        public string Keyword { get; }

        public static bool TryParse(int value, out TableDetails tableDetails)
        {
            return TryParse(value.ToString(), out tableDetails);
        }

        public static bool TryParse(string value, out TableDetails tableDetails)
        {
            try
            {
                tableDetails= Parse(value);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                tableDetails= null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static TableDetails Parse(int value)
        {
            return Parse(value.ToString());
        }

        public static TableDetails Parse(string value)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case "1":
                case nameof(TableOneDetails):
                    return TableOneDetails;
                case "2":
                case nameof(TableTwoDetails):
                    return TableTwoDetails;
                case "3":
                case nameof(TableThreeDetails):
                    return TableThreeDetails;                
                default:                    
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(TableDetails)} doesn't contain {value}.");
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.Name;
        }
    }
```

You can now change your `GetTableRow` method to accept the type `TableDetails`. In addition you only have one parameter to pass in, the `TableDetails`, and if you need to add more parameters you can update your `TableDetails` object without having to change your `GetTableRow` method signature.

```
public static T GetTableRow(TableDetails tableDetails)
```

Comment: With yours and @juharr's suggestions, I started looking at Type Safe enums as this is the first time I have heard of it. Once I understood the general idea, I began writing my own until I saw this answer which further helped me understand Type Safe enums

Answer (score 0):

Contrain a type is difficult (unless it is a generic type), what you could do is create a type parameter on the method to the enum and constrain it to the enum type:

```cs
... GetTableRow<TEnum>(... TEnum prefix, ...) : where TEnum : EnumType {}
```

, or just throw an exception if enum is not the type you want.

Comment: Note that it is different than saying `where T: Enum`, but rather: `where T: TheTypeYouWant`.

Comment: There is no actual difference between `GetTableRow<TEnum>(TEnum prefix) : where TEnum : EnumType` and `GetTableRow(EnumType prefix)` in this case.

Comment: That is right, therefore overloading or exception throwing would be more efficient.